# Replace \cline with \cmidrule throughout document

Tags: rules, booktabs

I have several tables that are automatically outputted by a statistical package, with `\cline` commands for groups of column headers.  I'm including these tables using `\input` in a larger document, and I'd like to convert all of the `\cline` calls to the more attractive `\cmidrule`.  Obviously I can manually change them, but this will get tedious if I have to re-generate the tables.

I've tried `\renewcommand{\cline}[1]{\cmidrule(lr){#1}}`, but this does something strange.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\renewcommand{\cline}[1]{\cmidrule{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!tbp]

{\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrcrrcrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries }&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Group1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries }&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Group 2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries }&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Group 3}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name (\$)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name (\$)}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'll note that creating the extra empty columns to give space between the clines is an artifact of the stats package, which I unfortunately can't avoid without a lot more work.

Comment: unrelated but `{\centering \begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}` does not center the tabular, you need a blank line before the final `}`

Comment: That's another artifact of the output process, or possibly my reducing it down to a minimal-working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands look ahead to check for a following command on the same row so you need something with the "expected" definition of `\cmidrule`. Using `\let` works here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\let\cline\cmidrule
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!tbp]

{\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrcrrcrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries }&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Group1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries }&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Group 2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries }&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Group 3}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name (\$)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name (\$)}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, that works, thanks.  Could you explain a little more why that works though?  I didn't follow the "expected" distinction.

Comment: @rsandler it uses `\futurelet` (or latex's `\@ifnextchar`) wrapper for that) to get a csname say `\tmp` that represents "the next thing"  then does `\ifx\tmp\cmidrule two midrule on a row \else end of the current sequence of midrules \fi` You defined `\cline` to be a macro expanding to  `\cmidrule` but the `ifx` test is always false in that case. `\let` makes `\cline` have the same definition as `\cmidrule` so the `ifx` is true when tested

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. Instead of redefining the `\cline` macro, it sets up a Lua function that simply replaces all instances of `\cline` in the input file with `\cmidrule(lr)` "on the fly" at a very early stage of processing, i.e, before TeX starts its normal work.

The advantage of this approach, when compared to the `\let\cline\cmidrule` approach, is *increased flexibility*, e.g., one can set up the function to replace all occurrences of `\cline` with `\cmidrule(lr)`, as is done in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function c2c ( s )
  return ( string.gsub ( s , "\\cline" , "\\cmidrule(lr)" )) 
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , c2c, "c2c" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrr crr crr}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Group 1}&
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Group 2}&
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Group 3}\\
\cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name (\$)}&
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name (\$)}\\
\midrule
abc \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```